# command xen-create-image gives error

Tags: xen

I want to install domU i tried the command given below.

```
 xen-create-image --hostname=machine-0 --memory=512mb --vcpus=2 --lvm=vg0 --dhcp --pygrub --dist=wheezy --force
```

It gives error and the log look like give below. just see that if you can give me some tips it will be more helpful.

### /var/log/xen-tools/machine-0.log

```
I: Retrieving Packages
I: Validating Packages
W: Retrying failed download of http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
I: Retrieving Packages
I: Validating Packages
 W: Retrying failed download of http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
I: Retrieving Packages
I: Validating Packages
W: Retrying failed download of http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
I: Retrieving Packages
I: Validating Packages
W: Retrying failed download of http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
I: Retrieving Packages
I: Validating Packages
W: Retrying failed download of http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
I: Retrieving Packages
I: Validating Packages
W: Retrying failed download of http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
W: http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages was corrupt
E: Couldn't download dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages
WARNING (/usr/bin/xt-install-image): The installed system at /tmp/1Ip3F1ZS8l doesn't seem to be a full system.
WARNING (/usr/bin/xt-install-image): The installed system is missing the common file: /bin/ls.
WARNING (/usr/bin/xt-install-image): The installed system at /tmp/1Ip3F1ZS8l doesn't seem to be a full system.
WARNING (/usr/bin/xt-install-image): The installed system is missing the common file: /bin/cp.

Copying files from new installation to host.
Copying files from /tmp/1Ip3F1ZS8l/var/cache/apt/archives -> /var/cache/apt/archives/
Done
Done
Done
System installation failed.  Aborting
umount: /tmp/1Ip3F1ZS8l/proc: not found
Running command 'umount /tmp/1Ip3F1ZS8l/proc 2>&1' failed with exit code 256.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the mirror is giving you problems. I used to install Debian machines using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xen-create-image --genpass=0 --memory=512M --noswap --pygrub --ip=192.168.1.10 \
                   --gateway=192.168.1.1  netmask=255.255.255.0 \
                   --password="****" --force --size=12G \
                   --vcpus=1 --arch=amd64 \
                   --hostname=VM1 --lvm=GuestSwapRoot \
                   --mirror=http://cdn.debian.net/debian \
                   --dist=wheezy
```